# How to decrease EBS volume size via snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ebs

When I am creating a volume from a snapshot but I want to decrease the size the there is an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** to reduce the size of an Amazon EBS volume.

You will need to create a new volume, then copy files across using the operating system.